# Open raster using rasterio and s3

Tags: django, docker, amazon-s3, gis, rasterio

I'm storing rasters in Amazon S3 bucket and would like to open specific object using installed rasterio library in my Django docker container.

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID are incluced in docker-compose.yml env variables.

Inside docker container and trying:

```
$ python manage.py shell
$ import rasterio
$ with rasterio.open(url_to_s3_object) as file:
$ ....print(file)
```

I'm receiving error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rasterio/_base.pyx", line 72, in rasterio._base.DatasetReader.start (rasterio/_base.c:2847)
  File "rasterio/_base.pyx", line 74, in rasterio._base.DatasetReader.start (rasterio/_base.c:2799)
  File "rasterio/_err.pyx", line 196, in rasterio._err.CPLErrors.check (rasterio/_err.c:1773)
  rasterio._err.CPLE_OpenFailed: {URL TO S3 OBJECT} does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

What is the solution for that?

In local machine everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution for that. rasterio lib works correct with s3 under GDAL 2.1.0 at least - https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/vsi.rst#aws-s3
Upgrading GDAL solves the problem.

Comment: The given link is broken.

Comment: @zabop The link is updated to a valid one